# How to switch from Google Chart Tools to D3.JS?

Tags: javascript, d3.js, visualization, google-visualization

I use `Google Charts` to visualize a match data, but I want to use `D3.JS` from now on because of its large community and rich graphic tools. I had written a code for [Google Chart](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Google_Chart_API), which pulls data from database, parses it with [JSON](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON) format, and visualizes via a basic bar chart. I want to change my basic bar chart to a [stacked bar chart](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3886208).

- Here is my [script](http://pastebin.com/eJMGqe3t).
- [My Google chart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6YYF9.jpg)

I looked around to find a solution, but I couldn't find exactly what I needed.

How can I switch it to `D3.JS`?

Comment: D3 is great, but it involves a decent bit of hand coding when you start. I doubt there is any automatic tool such as you desire, though it's not impossible. Start with one of the d3 examples that resembles what you want, sub in your data, then play around.

Answer (score 1):

## NVD3 Re-usable charts for d3.js

> This project is an attempt to build re-usable charts and chart
>   components for d3.js without taking away the power that d3.js gives
>   you. This is a very young collection of components, with the goal of
>   keeping these components very customizeable, staying away from your
>   standard cookie cutter solutions.

Try this, it might be what you're looking for: http://nvd3.org/ghpages/multiBarHorizontal.html

Let us know if it does the job.

Answer (score 1):

vida.io is another option for reusable d3js templates. You can do live edit of javascript and stylesheet. In addition, vida.io offers GUI editor for basic properties, data upload for you to upload csv files.

Check out demo section for more examples:

https://vida.io/explore

Disclaimer: my team runs vida.io.

Comment: link no longer works